# To either revive or kill something

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, prefixes

I'm wondering if there's a word out there for me. I think that a clever use of a prefix would do as well.

So, to **revive** means to make alive, and to **kill** means to make dead. Is there a word that means to toggle someone or something's life/death status?

Alternatively, and I know that this is a long shot, but I could use a word or phrase that means changing one's mind (or pronunciation) regarding the **life/death status** of inanimate objects (or living things).

Related: is there a medical term for disagreement about a patient's **life/death status**?

Is there a natural prefix that means '**toggle**' or '**switch**'?

Is there a word that means **life/death status**, similar to how 'beatitude' might describe blessed/unblessed status?

EDIT: I'm going with 'transanimate'. Thanks for the help!

Comment: But 'beatitude' *doesn't* describe 'blessed/unblessed status' - it only describes *blessedness*. Come to that, *revive/kill* wouldn't be understood as 'opposites' outside the computer gaming context where the attribute 'life' can be repeatedly and casually toggled. If you're looking for a computer game term, common ones are **vitality** and **health** - particularly in contexts where a value of 100 (percent) means you're 'fully alive/fighting fit', and 0 means you're dead/game over.

Comment: In medicine, can't the status of death be granted or revoked?

Comment: Not really. Generally speaking, the status of being dead is an objective fact, not something that can be altered by subjective assessment or a change of opinion.

Comment: Revive doesn't mean to make alive, it means to restore to life. That is, one cannot revive something that was not previously alive.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably [Romans 7:9](http://bible.cc/romans/7-9.htm) and the surrounding verses probably have the clearest references to toggling aliveness: "I was once alive apart from the law, but when the commandment came, sin came alive and I died." Since this venerable reference has no better term for it, I have to imagine that there is none.

Looking up "to hover between life and death," I found "terminal state," which may serve for "life/death status."

Is "trans-" the closest prefix to the meaning "switch" or "toggle"?

Perhaps you should coin a term?

> I togglived ("toggle-lived") him.

or:

> He gave me no choice, so I trans-slew him.

Comment: Yes! 'trans-' can mean 'to or on the other side of.' So 'transanimate' does the job, I think. I will use it.

Comment: Do you have any examples of *transXXXX* where the *trans-* prefix means "toggle the state XXXXX on or off"? I'm not aware of any - it usually means *across* (transatlantic), or *beyond* (transhuman).

Comment: @FumbleFingers: [Transmogrifier](http://1.bp.blogspot.com/-uJnx12H8nS0/TcCvYjOj5-I/AAAAAAAAAKM/6e6TgsfN0rU/s1600/transmogrifier_2.gif)? ;^) Shipr:  _"Since this venerable reference has no better term for it, I have to imagine that there is none."_ No offense to Paul or the New Testament, but that's a pretty [weak](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Affirming_a_disjunct) logical argument.

Comment: @J.R.: Not that it will save shipr's bacon here, but I'll grant you *transmogrify* is an interesting word. OED says it's *vulgar or humorous* (a pre-Victorian equivalent of today's *humungous, cromulent, embiggen*, I guess). But they don't have much idea what it came from, or how to interpret the *trans* "prefix". To quote - *If the original form was transmigrafy , this may have been a vulgar or uneducated formation in -fy from transmigure v., or transmigrate v. (compare transmigration n. 3b). Apparently, it was originally persons that were ‘transmografied’, or metamorphosed.*

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1 to you for recognizing the weakness in my "argument"!  Which is why I said "probably" - twice! - and "I have to imagine" and give credit to its "venerable" status.

Comment: Whoops, a little confusion there. My other comment was to @J.R. To FumbleFingers, verbs such as "transship" indeed use "trans-" to mean across, but to cross the boundary between two mutually exclusive states produces toggling. So I think "transanimate" is a good choice here.  And remember: I phrased it as a question, not an assertion.

Comment: @shipr: I wouldn't blow the trumpet for *transanimate* too much. OED says it's *obsolete and rare*, and Google mostly thinks I must be looking for *transaminate* (the reversible exchange of amino groups between different amino acids). So, not really a good choice to illustrate anything, imho.

Answer (score 2):

While I am not aware of a term that describes the switch between alive and dead, *[aliveness](http://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/aliveness)* describes life/death status

> the quality of being alive

It appears to have an increasing [usage](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aliveness&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) in both British and American English.

Comment: ['Animation'](http://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=aliveness%2C+animation&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=0&smoothing=3) was more popular before 1900; I guess my search is narrowing down to something like a conditional 'reanimate' and 'deanimate'.

Comment: @zpmorgan *Animation* came to mind, but the multiple meanings gave me pause.

Comment: I found it by looking up 'aliveness' in an online thesaurus. 'reanimate' & 'deanimate' are less ambiguous, I think.

Answer (score -1):

How about using *toggle* or *torture*?

Comment: Can you expand on why you suggest those words, and possibly could you add relevant dictionary definitions supporting your suggestions?

Answer (score -2):

Well, in gaming terms there's *respawn*; which means you were killed and came back.

I would also add *resurrect* as a possibility but I can't think of a better fit.

Comment: Sure, but it has to be conditional; resurrect if dead & kill if alive.